# SQL Server 2008 query design toolbar greyed out

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have used SQL Server 2008 Management Studio for a long time and all of a sudden I noticed the query design toolbar which has change type on it and allows you to execute query from there and select other options, all greyed out.

Does anyone know how to correct this? I have restarted Management Studio numerous times.

Answer (score 3):

The Query Design toolbar is only available when you do the following:

- Right Click object (e.g Table)
- Select "Edit Top 200 Rows"
- Query Designer toolbar is enabled